# Enviar un formulario por correo

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

hola a todos bueno estoy tratando como puedo enviar  un formulario que contiene php    a un correo  CON PHPMAILER

<<<---SCRIP---->>>

```
$mail->Body = "<table style='max-width: 600px; padding: 10px; margin:0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;'>


    <tr>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='background-color:White'>
            <div style='color: #34495e; margin: 4% 0% 5%; text-align: justify;font-family: sans-serif'>
                <h2 style='color: #e67e22; margin: 0 0 7px'> Hola $nombre  $ApellidoP  $ApellidoM  !</h2>
                <p style='margin: 2px; font-size: 15px'>
                    Gracias, por registrarte y participar en nuestro evento. Esta es la confirmacion de asistencia para: 
                    <h3>I CONGRESO TECNOLOGICO EMPRESARIAL:</h3>
                    <h3>APLICACION DE LA TECNOLOGIA PARA EL EMPRENDIMIENTO EMPRESARIAL</h3><br>
                </p>


                    <P style='text-decoration: underline;'>Organizado por:</P>
                <P style='font-weight:bold'>    Universidad Peruana de Ciencias e Informatica</P>
                   <P style='font-weight:bold'>  Facultad de Ciencia Empresariales y Negocios</p>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                    <br>
                    <div id='Div'>

                  <a style='visibility:hidden'> </a>
                </div>


                <p>多Tienes Alguna pregunta  Sobre el evento?</p>   
                <a href='http://www.mmconsultoresinformaticos.net/contactanos.html' target='_blank'>Ponte en Contacto con el organizador</a>   

        <br>
        <br>        
        <style>
.normal {
width: 800px;
  border:2px solid #000;
}
.normal th {
 border: 1px solid #000;
  color :red;
}
.normal td{
 border: 1px solid #000;
  color :blue;
}           
</style>        

                <table class='normal'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>CHARLAS</th>
                                            <th>EXPOSITOR</th>
                                            <th>FECHA</th>
                                           <th>HORA</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>



                   <?php  


              for($i = 1 ; $i<=30 ; $i++){

          $chalae = 'Charla'; 

                    if ($i <10)
                           {
                             $varE = $chalae.'0'.$i;  

                            }


                            elseif($i >= 10 and $i <=20)

                            {
                                 $varE = $chalae.$i ;   

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $chalaee = 'charla';
                                $varE = $chalaee.$i ; 
                            }

                      $result = mysql_query('select $varE  from tbl_inscripcion_congreso where codBarra= '$rando1n'');

                         while($fila =mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                    $valDatos = $fila[$varE] ;
                       if ($valDatos !='')


                 $result2 = mysql_query('select expocitor ,  fecha1 , Hora from tbl_charlas where Charla='$valDatos'');

                while($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))    

                  { ?>
                    <tr class='success'>  
                 <td><?php  echo $fila[$varE]?></td>    
                    <td><?php echo $fila2'['expocitor']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila2'['fecha1'] ?></td>        
                  <td><?php echo $fila2'['Hora']?></td>                     
                    </tr>
                    <br>

                      <?php    
                  } 
                  }}?>    

                             </tbody>
            </table>





        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>";
```

Comment: ¿Que problema estas experimentando? ¿En que parte de tu codigo tienes el problema? ¿Cual es tu pregunta? Si no pones algo especifico en que podamos ayudarte, puede ser que cierren tu pregunta.

Comment: Envia correctamente el correo pero la  la sintaxis de php no lo reconoce

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada para subir tu reputacion y ayudar en la calidad del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

**Respuesta corta.**

Antes de asignarle a `$mail` todo lo que quieres enviar, ejecuta tus consultas, guardarlas en un string y concatenalo a tu tabla de html. Algo así:

```
$tabla_php = "<tr class='success'><td>";
for($i = 1 ; $i<=30 ; $i++){
    $chalae = 'Charla'; 
    if ($i <10)
        $varE = $chalae.'0'.$i;  
    elseif($i >= 10 and $i <=20)
        $varE = $chalae.$i ;
    else
    {
        $chalaee = 'charla';
        $varE = $chalaee.$i ; 
    }
    $result = mysql_query('select $varE  from tbl_inscripcion_congreso where codBarra= '$rando1n'');
    while($fila =mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $valDatos = $fila[$varE] ;
        if ($valDatos !='')
            $result2 = mysql_query('select expocitor ,  fecha1 , Hora from tbl_charlas where Charla='$valDatos'');
        while($fila2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))    
        { 
            $tabla_php = $tabla_php.$fila[$varE]."</td><td>".$fila2'['expocitor']."</td><td>".$fila2'['fecha1']."</td><td>".$fila2'['Hora']."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora, en tu string `$mail` sustituye toda esa parte de php que empieza despues de `<tbody>` por lo que tienes en la variable `$tabla_php`

```
"...<tbody>".$tabla_php."</tbody>..."
```

Los puntos suspensivos representan toda la parte restante del string que tienes en `$mail`.

**Respuesta Larga.**

PHP es un lenguaje que, en este caso, solo entiende tu servidor, es decir, tu computadora en donde estas corriendo tu servicio web. Lo que estas haciendo en este codigo es guardando en la variable `$mail` un muy grande `string` que tiene muchas cosas dentro, como etiquetas de HTML y etiquetas para iniciar scripts de PHP, pero al final, solamente es un string. Cuando la persona del otro lado abre el correo electronico, la computadora de esta persona lo unico que entiende es un muy grande `string`. Claro, las etiquetas HTML las entenderá, pero las instrucciones en PHP no, porque no tiene ningun programa instalado en PHP que pueda ejecutar estas instrucciones. Debes recordar que todo lo que tenga etiquetas PHP se ejecuta en tu computadora y no en las computadoras que requieren la pagina web.